# How to route to same location in angular 10?

Tags: angular, router

I have a really weird problem , After a successful api call I want to refresh my page. I am using the below code

```
 this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
 this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
 this.router.navigate(['fund/initiation/create']
```

Interestingly this changes all the url links in the menu bar to point to this above given url and then I can navigate to other pages. How to avoid this?

Comment: This is not a question. We don't know if have a problem or you juste share some info. 1st case, we can't answer, 2nd case this is not the best way to share something :)

Comment: window.location.reload() and location.reload()